# LWUIT 1.5 for Mac OS Development

Tags: java-me, lwuit, netbeans-7, codenameone

I want to make mobile application using Netbeans 7.0 on Mac OS, I'm using LWUIT 1.5 but the application is not working although it is working in another Windows computer but using

Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2, but now when I used Wireless Toolkit 3.0 for Netbeans 1.5 it does not work and I have the following error

> *** Error *** A problem occured during deploying application from http://127.0.0.1:52182/HelloLWUIT.jad Reason: Installing suite from:
>   http://127.0.0.1:52182/HelloLWUIT.jad Corrupt JAR, error while
>   reading: HelloLWUITMidlet.class
>   /Users/Veripark/NetBeansProjects/HelloLWUIT/nbproject/build-impl.xml:915:
>   Execution failed with error code 1.

can anyone please tell me how to install Wireless Toolkit 2.5.2 on Mac OS

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that if I create the project on Mac so I can't compile it or run it on windows, I just take the code and create new project in windows and the problem solved

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to use CodenameOne?  http://www.codenameone.com/

take a look on that, is compatible with LWUIT solutions.